# Paypal .NET SDK order authorization always 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I always get a 404 `Bad Request` when i want to get an order or try to authorize a order.

I tried the REST API way:

```cs
var config = new Dictionary<string, string>
{{ "mode", "sandbox" }, { "clientId", "123" },{ "clientSecret", "ABC" }};

var token = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"{token}");
var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(string.Empty), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1234567/authorize", content, CancellationToken.None);
```

Response 404..

---

I tried the SDK way with the official [paypal lts sdk](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal). Check this here:

```cs
var config = new Dictionary<string, string>
{{ "mode", "sandbox" }, { "clientId", "123" },{ "clientSecret", "ABC" }};

var token =  new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        
var orderId = "1234566";
var context = new APIContext(token);
var order = Order.Get(context, orderId);
```

Response 404...

You can find the official test of the authorize function here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/releasinator/Source/Tests/OrderTest.cs

---

But... if i use cURL - everything went well.

```bash
curl -v -X POST https: //api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/1234566/authorize \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer asdasd"
```

Its also no problem to get information about a order with http-get method.

```cs
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/2134566", CancellationToken.None);
```

Maybe someone knows a trick or a hack or see my mistake.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: From what can be told by the information in the question, Authorization header value appears incorrect, but that would give a 400/401 type error not a 404. You should log the entire response of this "404" since it will have more details.

Comment: Possible reasons of an actual 404 include creating an order ID with a different clientid+secret or environment (sandbox vs. live) and then attempting to authorize it with different credentials/environment. To determine whether that is happening, the entire order creation response as well as the full authorization request (including url path) and authorization response should be looked at. No placeholder values.

Comment: i used the accesstoken in booth options (as curl and with the sdk / httpclient post). 
I don't think it has anything to do with the authentication. otherwise it wouldn't work with curl either.
I will post the entire stacktrace later this day. thanks for your reply.

Comment: The curl authentication appears correct. The http client code does not appear correct, from what we can see of it. In particular, the value the Authorization header is being set to.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way how it works. if i create the token via REST everything is good. . without the "sandbox mode"

```cs
using var client = new HttpClient();
var credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{paypalCredentials.ClientId}:{paypalCredentials.ClientSecret}"));
var content = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentials);
        
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{paypalCredentials.BaseUri}oauth2/token", content, cancellationToken);
```

in the response is the token. Then authorize it.

```cs
 using var client = new HttpClient();
var responseContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{_paypalCredential.BaseUri}checkout/orders/{orderId}/authorize", responseContent, cancellationToken);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
```

and then capture everthing by the paypal rest api